# How can I automatically record the terminal session every time a new terminal window is opened?

Tags: linux, bash

I have a script I would like to run when a terminal is opened. This will use the `script` command to record the terminal session, to aid in troubleshooting the system after some software work is done.  When I placed the script in .bash.d, and opened a terminal, it gets stuck in a loop repeatedly starting the script.

script -a -f ~/user_data/error_logs/terminal_output/typescript.$(hostname).$(date -I).txt

Comment: How do you know it gets stuck in a loop? How did you come to that conclusion?

Comment: replace your command with `date >> debug.txt` or `script -a -c date debug.txt` and check for a loop.

Comment: when I open a new terminal it repeatedly displays in the command line that it is starting the script and I have to ctrl c to stop it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix it by placing the following in the .bashrc

```
test "$(ps -ocommand= -p $PPID | awk '{print $1}')" == 'script' || (/data/file_upload/term_log.sh)
```

The contents of term_log.sh are:

```
script -a -f -q ~/user_data/error_logs/terminal_output/typescript.txt
kill -9 $PPID
```

I added the kill -9 $PPID so that when a user typed exit it would close the terminal and not just quit the script.

Answer (score 1):

I have never used `bash.d`. But I put commands I would like to run at the start of terminal or more specifically bash in `~/.bash_profile` and it works like charm.

You will have to close the bash session and start a fresh session for the command you put in `~/.bash_profile` to take effect, as commands in `~/.bash_profile` are executed only when the bash session starts. Alternatively, after you have put the command in `~/.bash_profile`, you can run `source ~/.bash_profile` for the command to take effect.

Comment: Don't forget about the if statement so it doesn't run multiple times if for example `source .bash_profile` is used.

Comment: can you clarify "if" statement?  Im still learning as I go any help is appreciated!